# What exact time will chat bot migrate to version 2?

Tags: dialogflow-es

What exact time will Dialog flow migrate to version 2? I already know October date is 23 of October

Answer (score 0):

Dialogflow has already released v2.

Dialogflow has already deprecated API v1 and they will be shutting this down on **October 23th, 2019**. In order to make sure your dialogflow agent keeps working after shutdown, you need to make sure you migrate your actions/intents to Dialogflow’s API V2.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but i needed to know exact time of shutting down v1. Like PST time zones